# Almost simple groups and their involutions without CFSG

Tags: finite-groups, group-actions, involutions, classification, centralisers

Suppose $A$ is a finite *almost simple group* (meaning, by definition, that there exists a finite simple group $P$ such that $P \leq A \leq \mathrm{Aut}(P)$). Suppose furthermore that $A$ acts $2$-transitively on some set $X$.

My first question might be too general: (1) what can we say about the structure of $A$ (or $(A,X)$) without making use of the classification of finite simple groups (CFSG) ?

*Second and third question* (again without CFSG): (2) what can we say about the action of involutions in $(A,X)$, and (3) what is known about the size/structure of a centralizer in $A$ of an involution ?

Comment: The first question was studied for many decades by many people, and not well understood without CFSG. As for the second question, the question of classifying transitive permutation groups in which every involution fixes exactly one point was achieved without CFSG by H. Bender, and played an important  role in the eventual classification ( look up strongly embedded subgroups if you don't know about them).

Comment: Note that such groups always turn out to be doubly transitive.